# Constructing an LC-3 symbol table

Tags: lc3, symbol-table

I have a question about symbol tables. Now according to my textbook the rules of a symbol table are as follows:

1. Find the .ORIG statement,
   which tells us the address of the first instruction and initialize location counter (LC), which keeps track of the
   current instruction.
2. For each non-empty line in the program:
   a) If line contains a label, add label and LC to symbol table.
   b) Increment LC.
   – NOTE: If statement is .BLKW or .STRINGZ,
   increment LC by the number of words allocated.
3. Stop when .END statement is reached.

I'm having a problem with the second rule. Specifically, the statement about .BLKW or .STRINGZ (increment LC by the number of words allocated). I could not find any example in the textbook that could help me understand this, but I did find some code online.

In my example code, what are the addresses of the statements that contain .BLKW and .STRINGZ?

```
01 .ORIG x 3000
02 
03 INIT
04     LEA   R0, START.STR
05     JSR   PRINST.STR
06     LD    R0, TEN
07     LEA   R1, DATA.B
08     
09 STORE_LOOP
10     STR   RO, R1, %0
11     ADD   R1, R1, %1
12     ADD   R0, R0, %-1
13     BRp   ST.LOOP
14     
15     LD    R0, TEN
16     ADD   R1, R1, %-1
17     AND   R2, R2, %0
18
19 ADD_LOOP
20     LDR   R3, R1, %0
21     ADD   R2, R3, R2
22     ADD   R1, R1, %-1
23     ADD   R0, R0, %-1
24     BRp   ADD_LOOP
25
26 STORE_SUM
27     ST    R2, RESULT
28     TRAP  %25
29
30 PRINT_STR
31     ST    R7, SAVE.R7
32     PUTS
33     LD    R7, SAVE.R7
34     RET
35
36  TEN       .FILL #10
37  SAVE.R7   .BLKW #1
38  DATA.B    .BLKW #10
39  START_STR .STRINGZ "Starting..."
40  RESULT    .FILL #0
41  END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code annotated with comments showing the address of each one.

```
01 .ORIG x 3000
02 
03 INIT                             ; x3000
04     LEA   R0, START.STR          ; x3000
05     JSR   PRINST.STR             ; x3001
06     LD    R0, TEN                ; x3002
07     LEA   R1, DATA.B             ; x3003
08     
09 STORE_LOOP                       ; x3004
10     STR   RO, R1, %0             ; x3004
11     ADD   R1, R1, %1             ; x3005
12     ADD   R0, R0, %-1            ; x3006
13     BRp   ST.LOOP                ; x3007
14     
15     LD    R0, TEN                ; x3008
16     ADD   R1, R1, %-1            ; x3009
17     AND   R2, R2, %0             ; x300A
18
19 ADD_LOOP                         ; x300B
20     LDR   R3, R1, %0             ; x300B
21     ADD   R2, R3, R2             ; x300C
22     ADD   R1, R1, %-1            ; x300D
23     ADD   R0, R0, %-1            ; x300E
24     BRp   ADD_LOOP               ; x300F
25
26 STORE_SUM                        ; x3010
27     ST    R2, RESULT             ; x3010
28     TRAP  %25                    ; x3011
29  
30 PRINT_STR                        ; x3012
31     ST    R7, SAVE.R7            ; x3012
32     PUTS                         ; x3013
33     LD    R7, SAVE.R7            ; x3014
34     RET                          ; x3015
35
36  TEN       .FILL #10             ; x3016
37  SAVE.R7   .BLKW #1              ; x3017
38  DATA.B    .BLKW #10             ; x3018
39  START_STR .STRINGZ "Starting..."; x3022
40  RESULT    .FILL #0              ; x302E
41  END
```

Things to note.

1. Whenever you encounter a BLKW you add however many addresses it is reserving.
2. Whenever you encounter a .stringz you add however many characters that are in the string PLUS 1 for the NUL terminator character.

Also (for at least the tools I work with) some assemblers / simulators will generate a symbol table file when assembling, and some simulators will visibly show what labels are at what addresses.

Comment: I think I got it but im confused on how you are adding x3022 and 1C on line 39 to line 40 to get the result x303E. What is the logic behind that as this was the only way i got these answers.

Comment: 1) x3018 + 10 = x3022

2) x3022 + 12 = x302E

Miscalculation on the second one